# using INotifyPropertyChanged, thread issues

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am new with LightSwitch.
I'm trying to catch event when a checkbox control is being checked.
In the creation of the screen I wrote :

> ```
>  partial void CreateNewEmployee_Created()
>     {
>         this.EmployeeProperty.Contractors = new Contractor();
>
>         Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
>             {
>                 ((INotifyPropertyChanged) this.EmployeeProperty).PropertyChanged +=
>                  new PropertyChangedEventHandler(CreateNewEmployee_PropertyChanged);
>
>             });
>     }
> ```

and handling the event in CreateNewEmployee_PropertyChanged

> ```
>     private void CreateNewEmployee_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if(this.EmployeeProperty.IsContractor)
>         {
>
>             this.EmployeeProperty.Contractors = new Contractor();
>         }
>     }
> ```

I'm getting the excpetion in

> this.EmployeeProperty.Contractors = new Contractor();

The exception is

> A new instance of the EntityObject class cannot be initialized because
>   the ambient IDataWorkspace is not available.  Please use the
>   constructor that specifies an EntitySet.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using the default `CheckboxName_Changed()` method?

Comment: it seems like `this.EmployeeProperty.Contractors` that the `.Contractors` property is a _collection_. Maybe try `.Contractors.Add(new Contractor())` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using the AddNew() method

```
var c = this.EmployeeProperty.Contractors.AddNew()
```